# Joining select on one row for same result id

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, select, pivot

I have the following query result (I stored this result on a #TMP table)

```
Id  |  Letter  |  Column1  |  Column2
1   |  A       |  400      |  200
1   |  A       |  101      |  201
1   |  A       |  102      |  203
2   |  A       |  100      |  200
2   |  A       |  700      |  201
2   |  A       |  102      |  202
```

What I want to do is to make a select to that #TMP table but now I want my output like this:

```
Id  |  Letter  |  Alias1  |  Alias2  | Alias1-1  |  Alias2-1 |  Alias1-2  | Alias2-2
1   |  A       |  400     |  200     | 101       |  201      |  102       | 203  
2   |  A       |  100     |  200     | 700       |  201      |  102       | 202
```

How can I make this? I tried doing a join but I'm getting a lot of same results.

```
select A.Id, A.Letter, B.Column1, B.Column2
from #TMP A
inner join #TMP B ON A.Id = B.Id AND A.Letter = B.Letter
```

I also tried doing a group by

```
select Id, Letter, Column1, Column2
from #TMP
group by Id
```

But this query ask for letter, column1, column2 to be added to group by syntax and if I do it I get the same result like doing select * from #TMP

**PD: #TMP table always must contains 3 same id,letter rows**

**PD2: Column1 value could be greater than Column2 value in one row and in the next row column2 could be greater than column1 for results with same Id.**

Comment: You really need a row ordering column to ensure the same results each time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` window function together with `conditional aggregation`

```
with t(Id,Letter,Column1,Column2) as
(
    select 1,'A',100,200 union all
    select 1,'A',101,201 union all 
    select 1,'A',102,203 union all
    select 2,'A',100,200 union all
    select 2,'A',101,201 union all
    select 2,'A',102,202
), t2 as
(
select
    *,
    row_number() over (partition by Id,Letter order by Column1) as rn
  from [t]
)    
select Id,Letter,
       max(case when rn = 1 then Column1 end ) as [Alias1],
       max(case when rn = 2 then Column1 end ) as [Alias2],
       max(case when rn = 3 then Column1 end ) as [Alias1-1],
       max(case when rn = 1 then Column2 end ) as [Alias2-0],
       max(case when rn = 2 then Column2 end ) as [Alias2-1],
       max(case when rn = 3 then Column2 end ) as [Alias2-2] 
  from t2
 group by Id,Letter
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/RAEM75593)</kbd>